# Where can I find Alien Alloys?

Tags: xcom-2

I rushed Magnetic Weapons research, and to my dismay found that I can't actually build any magnetic weapons in engineering because I don't have any alien alloys.

I know in the first game that shooting down UFOs was a good source of them, but near as I can tell I'm not doing any UFO blasting in this game. Not yet anyway.

Is there anything I can do to hunt down alloys (like choosing certain mission types), or am I just kind of screwed for rushing Magnetic Weapons too early?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are five ways I know of to acquire Alien Alloys, ordered from most to least reliable:

- **Cleaning rooms** - The rooms on the lower levels of the Avenger will reward you with some units of alloy when cleaned out.
- **Black market** - The black market will often offer you alloys in exchange for intel.
- **Map drops** - From time to time "activities of interest" will appear on the global map which reward you some alloy when scanned for a few days.
- **Mission Rewards** - Sometimes you will receive missions to raid a supply convoy or a landed UFO. These will reward you with alloy.
- **Hacking rewards** - Sometimes you can get some alloy as a reward for successful hacking.

Answer (score 11):

There are several ways I know of to acquire Alien Alloys.

**UFO Missions** - one of the possible mission types is intercepting a landed or downed UFO. Like the original game, after the mission Alien Alloys can be claimed from the craft.

**Alien Machinery** - There are 3 types of rooms in the avenger. One of them is "Alien Machinery", and clearing this room type will give a small amount of Alien Alloys.

**Supply Raid Missions** - Supply Raid missions (Advent Trains) can result in Alien Alloys.

**Black Market** - The Black market will occasionally offer Alien Alloys. You must buy these lump sump for intel, and they aren't always available.

See also [Philipp's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/254528/336), above.

Comment: I later found the black market had some for sale too.

Answer (score 6):

You can also acquire alien alloys as a hack reward (albeit, with a low probability, dependent on your squad member's tech score) upon a successful hack, seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: "albeit, with a low probability" - if you mean those 5% and 1% unlock chances, that's because the soldier in this screenshot is a rookie. His hack stat appears to be 5. With a soldier who's actually good at hacking, ideally a specialist, you can get much better odds. (If you mean a low probability of alien alloys being the reward options, then yeah, they don't come up much.)

Comment: @user2357112 That's a good point; I've edited the answer a bit towards those lines

Comment: For reference I had a 60% chance of getting alloys with a "normal" specialist